# Car stalls when in reverse, did not turn back on today

Tags: honda, starting, stall, crv

My car will stall while i am in reverse sometimes, and usually i just have to turn it off and crank it again and it starts back up. Today, it stalled when i was backing up, so I turned the car off and tried cranking it a few times, but it did not start again.

Also, im not sure if stalling is the right word because im not really a car person. When it “stalls” the battery light comes on and I can no longer use my pedals and all i can really do is shift into park. Ive never thought to test if my lights and stuff still work but I assume they do not.

I cleaned the idle air control valve because my friend who is a mechanic said it could be an issue, but I think it might have made it worse for some reason as it started stalling more often after cleaning it. We hooked the code reader up and nothing showed up, other than low catalytic converter efficiency which I dont think is the issue because im assuming its a battery issue.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas to throw my way because im not sure it will start anymore and dont know what to do at this point.

Its a 2000 Honda CRV

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A few questions for perspective since no one knows your vehicle state of health. What's cold and warm engine idle rpm? Vehicle mileage? Last time air/oil/oil filter/spark plugs replaced? Using ac when reversing?

Comment: Cold idle rpm is around 1.5, and warm idle is closer to 1. It has 250,000 miles, Oil was changed around 3 months ago along with the oil filter. The air filter was cleaned a few months before that but not replaced, and the car was someone elses before me so im not sure when that or the spark plugs were last replaced. It has died with the ac both off and on while reversing.